# IIS 7.5 Basic authorization issue

Tags: iis-7.5, http-basic-authentication

When I log on using correct user name\password (I always copy-paste them) I get 401.1 error. User name and password are correct (user is created on server locally, not a domain one). I can run program as this user (runas /noprofile /user:tmp notepad.exe). Basic authorization's default domain is a server name, realm is empty.

I've saved FailedReqLogFile. AUTH_BASIC_LOGON_FAILED shows

`ErrorCode="Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (0x8007052e)"`

and MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS shows

`ModuleName="BasicAuthenticationModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", HttpStatus="401", HttpReason="Unauthorized", HttpSubStatus="1", ErrorCode="Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (0x8007052e)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""`

And one more thing - if I use my domain login\password it woks! Basic Authentications is only enabled authentication in application...

Could you please suggest me how I can troubleshoot and fix this issue? Maybe somebody hit it before...

Best regards,
Alex

UPDATE: I get 401.1 when I trying to access site from local host. I can actually access files from remote host.

Answer (score 1):

You receive error 401.1 when you browse a Web site that uses Integrated Authentication and is hosted on IIS 5.1 or a later version
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Use BackConnectionHostNames or DisableLoopBackCheck.

Comment: I've tried to set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck to 1 and reboot. Still have the same problem.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the article? First step was: To set the DisableLoopbackCheck registry key, follow these steps: 1.
Set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1. (Then set any of the other registry keys). Suggest you first confirm that the security event log entry at the top of the article matches your symptom when the logon fails.